# how to send the updated code for the ble to the ble device using our application

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an android application I want to integrate a feature in my app where I can send a zip file to the ble device to update the code of my peripheral from my application.
this is the ota part. 
Using bluetooth.
Like how nrf simulator app does that by selecting from the phone storage dfu.

Comment: check the Nordic DFU lib: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library

Comment: Thank you for this i already saw this but i dont understand what after i integrate the library to my application.

Comment: there is a lot of detailed documentation which explains everything

Comment: do you have a link to any tutorial that can make things clear for me. That would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I used documentation for that, I didn't look for tutorials. However you may search for the tutorial your self